# How to erase all database connections?

Tags: java, matlab, jdbc

I have a program which connects to different databases. One is a mysql database and the other is a postgresql database. At the moment the program consists of two subprograms which each individually connect to one of the databases. These programs do not exchange any information and are (at least for now) completely seperated. I stored the drivers in one common folder called `javaLibs`.

Now the following problem occurs:

When I start Matlab and execute subprogram A everything works fine. Then I close subprobram A. When I execute subprogram B afterwards matlab can't establish a proper connection because `Unable to find JDBC driver.`

If I restart Matlab and execute subprogram B first the same thing happens. B works fine but even after closing B, A can't find the driver.
They are not using the same drivers anda java files.
Also I executet `close all` and `clear all` in between.

I tried including `DeleteFcn` in the main figure of subprogram A and use `close(dbConn)` but this didn't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an issue with all these programs being able to find your driver. It has nothing to do with closing the connections.

Make use of [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html), because this is sounding like you're not doing so.

Comment: At first I thought this could be the case but as I said the program that I open first is able to find the driver, only the second one is not. It doesn't matter which is first or second.